# Unable to hibernate Kali Linux after deleting swap partition

Tags: boot, kali-linux, hibernate

I had mistakenly deleted my Kali Linux swap partition in GPARTED, which was around 7gb, and now I'm unable to hibernate my laptop. Also, my system is taking too much time during boot. It stuck when the logo of Kali Linux appears.

Answer (score 3):

During hibernation, the state of the machine is saved to the swap partition. So if the swap partition has been deleted, the machine can't hibernate. You should restore the swap partition or set up Kali to use a swap file instead (if possible).

As suggested, Kali is best used as a live distro, where you shouldn't have the need to hibernate.

Comment: If you recreate swap, you also have to update UUID in fstab. And slow boot is probably system looking for old swap UUID as you did not update or delete entry in fstab. Compare UUID of partitions with UUIDs in fstab: `lsblk -f` and `cat /etc/fstab`